# deducing general lambdas argument type

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20

I wish to pass void and single argumented direct lambdas to operator call

```
class My { public: template<typename Callable> operator >> (Callable &&callback){ callback(); return *this;}  };
```

When pass lambda with auto like

```
My a; a >> ([](){ std::cout << "void lambda called" });
```

and check inner variant for monostate, it works, calls my lambda,

but I don't know how to extract type from lambda argument to call std::visit for passed to operator lambda since there need to be a check for what type is currently sits in variant, only working for compile in MSVC 2022 solution for C++20 that call all provided lambda independently what type is in variant, and it starts fails if add monostate to typelist.

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Test {
public:
    Test(const std::variant<Ts...>& v) : my(v) {}
    template <typename Callable>
    auto operator|(Callable&& c) {
        // this will visit for all types (outut int = 6 bool = 1) but should just for int?
        std::visit([&](const auto& val) { std::invoke(c, val); }, std::as_const(my));

        return *this;

    }
private:
    std::variant<Ts...> my;
};
int main() {
    std::variant<bool, int> test_var = 6;

    // Create a Test object using the variant
    Test a(test_var);
    int x = 2;
    // Use the operator| on the Test object, not directly on the variant
    a | [&](const int& what_value) { std::cout << "int " << (what_value + x) << '\n'; };
    a | [](const bool& bool_is) { std::cout << bool_is << '\n'; };
    //a | [](const std::monostate& mono) { std::cout << "mono"; };
    return 0;
}
```

If I create object that hold type T and that lambda I can make this works fine even for monostate listed in variant or if it's in monostate value, then passed visiting lambdas won't be executed, but syntax like
`std::variant<std::monostate, float, int> a; Test(a) | on_type([](const auto &flt){ std::cout << flt; };

is long, like idea to wrap that call and pass  for on_type object lambda holder that do all job somehow by deducing what arument type instead of auto passed `Test(a) |[](const float &a){ std::cout << a; } // as this.`

broke head about 2 days and still no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632236/how-is-possible-to-deduce-function-argument-type-in-c

Comment: How do you plan to come up with a value of an arbitrary type, that would actually be meaningful to an arbitrary callback? What would "my work with Type" look like? Anyway, that won't work for a generic lambda like `[](auto x){ std::cout << x; }` that can be called with any type.

Comment: I do [](bool b){ std::cout << b; } so type is b, I do call operator | of my class that has variant<bool, int> var; I do typename <Callable> operator | (Callable &&callback) { std::visit(std::forward<Callable>(callback), var); and get error std::visit no overloaded function found, same for trying through std::invoke or put another [](auto val) { callback(val); } to visit... But It works if I specialize type in operator directly then do check std::is_same and then do my visit... but list all types is hell

Comment: So you want to visit a variant but only if the visitor is invokable with the stored type? Visit a wrapper that checks is_invocable with the visited type and only call the callback if it is. Trying to match function parameters is XY for this.

Comment: `std::visit([&](auto&& val) { using T = decltype(val); if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<Callback&, T>) { std::invoke(callback, std::forward<T>(val); }, var);` ?

Comment: Well I changed it a bit and this fix all my problems, 2 days of broke head thanks!   std::visit([&](auto&& val) {
    using T = decltype(val);
   if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<Callable&, T>)
    std::invoke(std::forward<Callable>(c), val);
    }, variant_holder);

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow exactly what you're trying to do. Are you saying "operator>>" should take a lambda with either no args or just a single arg only? If a single arg, then what should "operator>>" pass for that arg when it invokes "callback"? As for getting the argument type, you can use my [FunctionTraits](https://github.com/HexadigmSystems/FunctionTraits) library rather than try to roll your own (library is effectively single header only, free and fully documented).

The code below is very crude (quick and dirty) but shows you what's possible as it pertains to your particular issue. You'll (very) likely need to tailor it for your needs however which isn't completely clear to me (but the library now provides you with a full-scale tool if you need it).

Click [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zdfTsdaTr) to run it:

```
#include <iostream>

 // See https://github.com/HexadigmSystems/FunctionTraits
#include "TypeTraits.h"

// Everything in above header in this namespace
using namespace StdExt;

class My
{
public:

    template<typename Callable>
    My& operator >> (Callable &&callback)
    {
        // "Callable" takes no args?
        if constexpr (IsEmptyArgList_v<Callable>)
        {
            callback();
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        // "Callable" takes 1 arg (also checking
        // to make sure it's not variadic, i.e.,
        // "..." doesn't follow the 1st arg in
        // this case)
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        else if constexpr (ArgCount_v<Callable> == 1 && // Arg count (i.e., arity)
                           !IsVariadic_v<Callable>) // No "..." at the end
        {
            //////////////////////////////////////
            // Type of the 1st arg of "Callable"
            // (there's only one arg from check
            // above)
            //////////////////////////////////////
            using Type = ArgType_t<Callable, 0>;

            ///////////////////////////////////////
            // Ok, you've got the type, now what?
            // (what do you pass to "callback").
            // We'll just pass "Type" for now
            // (default constructed)
            ///////////////////////////////////////
            callback(Type());
        }
        else
        {
            // See "AlwaysFalse" in "TypeTraits.h"
            static_assert(AlwaysFalse<Callable>, "\"Callable\" must take zero or 1 arg only");
        }
         
         return *this;
    }

    template<typename Callable>
    My& operator << (Callable &&callback)
    {
        //////////////////////////////////////
        // Assumes "Callable" takes at least
        // 1 arg but see code above for how
        // to check the number of args
        //////////////////////////////////////
        using Type = ArgType_t<Callable, 0>;

        // Display the type (just to show you how)
        tcout << TypeName_v<Type> << _T("\n");

        //callback(val); // From your code

        return *this;
    }
};    

int main()
{
    My a1;
    a1 >> ([]()
          {
              tcout << _T("void lambda with 0 args called\n");
          });

    My a2;
    a2 >> ([](int x)
          {
              tcout << _T("void lambda with 1 arg called (") << x << _T(")\n");
          });          

    My b;
    b << ([](float x)
          {
              tcout << x;
          });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I modify post to more clean example what I do

Comment: You apparently corrected the problem to your satisfaction based on your updated comment in the original post. Your updated code however has significant changes compared to what you originally posted. Good idea to post a clean and understandable example in the first place (I know it may not be easy though sometimes). I (and others) would have to re-examine your updated code all over again (my solution above based on my limited understanding of the original code).

Comment: Your library for strip (unwrap) lambda data seems good to go with expand my job of visiting std::variant though lambda passed to operator that holds instance of variant and determine it's type required to fire callback if matches with those lying in variant. I will try to inject some techniques and see how it fly, make big progress in neighbor topic that problem begins from what I try to create : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77835858/rangesview-pipe-operator-monadic-chains-for-stdvisit-by-hide-stdvariant